# Importing data into r from hive using RJDBC

Tags: r, hadoop, jdbc

My data resides in hive database on azure cloud and the link is "https://onetaxsitintegratedcluster.azurehdinsight.net/#/main/view/HIVE/random_instance
". I have the userid and password for the same. I tried to read data from R using the following but it throws an error

```
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", 
            "C:/Users/japrab/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RJDBC/java/hive-jdbc-2.0.0.jar")

conn <- dbConnect(drv,"https://integratedcluster.azurehdinsight.net/#/main/view/HIVE/random_instance", "userid", "passwords")
```

The error I get is:

```
options( java.parameters = "-Xmx8g" )
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "C:/Users/japrab/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/RJDBC/java/hive-jdbc-2.0.0.jar")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "integratedcluster.azurehdinsight.net/#/main/view/HIVE/random_instance", "user", "password")
```

Error in .verify.JDBC.result(jc, "Unable to connect JDBC to ", url) : 
  Unable to connect JDBC to integratedcluster.azurehdinsight.net/#/main/view/HIVE/auto_hive20_instance

Please help. All the examples I see have localhost but unsure what do i do when data is on a cloud!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you quote the hive jar from your own system. If your data is loaded in a Hive database in the cloud, the cloud server must be running Hadoop and Hive itself. I believe it is those jars that you need to reference.